# C# JSON Deserialization System.NotSupportedException

Tags: c#, json

Estou criando uma API básica para fins didáticos, e estou tendo alguns problemas para realizar um POST para a mesma. Minha classe seria a seguinte:

```
public class Product : BaseEntity, IProduct
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Default constructor
        /// </summary>
        public Product(string name, decimal price, long quantity, bool active = true)
        {
            SetName(name);
            SetPrice(price);
            SetQuantity(quantity);
            SetRegistrationDate();
            SetActive(active);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor with optional parameters
        /// </summary>
        public Product(string description, string name, decimal price, long quantity, bool active = true)
        {
            SetDescription(description);
            SetName(name);
            SetPrice(price);
            SetQuantity(quantity);
            SetRegistrationDate();
            SetActive(active);
        }

        public string Name { get; private set; }
        public string Description { get; private set; }
        public decimal Price { get; private set; }
        public long Quantity { get; private set; }
        public DateTime? RegistrationDate { get; private set; }
        public DateTime ChangeDate { get; private set; }
        public bool Active { get; private set; }
        public Guid CategoryId { get; private set; }
        public Category Category { get; private set; }

        //Methods............
```

Ao tentar realizar uma requisição POST, estou obtendo a seguinte exceção:

```
System.NotSupportedException: Deserialization of types without a parameterless constructor, a singular parameterized constructor, or a parameterized constructor annotated with 'JsonConstructorAttribute' is not supported. Type 'BlasterDomain.Models.Product'. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1.
```

Meu método POST dentro do meu Controller foi declarado da seguinte forma:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Product>> Post([FromServices] DataContext context, [FromBody] Product model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            context.Products.Add(model);
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return Ok(model);
        }
        else
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
    }
```

JSON utilizado para o POST:

```
{
"Name":"Product 1",
"Decription":"Product test",
"Price":"20.00",
"Quantity":"5"
}
```

Alguém saberia me informar onde estou falhando? Agradeço desde já :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A própria mensagem já te dá uma dica do que pode ser

```
System.NotSupportedException: Deserialization of types without a parameterless constructor, a singular parameterized constructor, or a parameterized constructor annotated with 'JsonConstructorAttribute' is not supported. Type 'BlasterDomain.Models.Product'. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1.
```

Remova os construtores da classe Product, deixando-a como segue abaixo

```
public class Product {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public long Quantity { get; set; }
    public DateTime? RegistrationDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime ChangeDate { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public Guid CategoryId { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

Ou adicione um construtor sem parâmetro

```
public Product() {

}
```

Comment: Realmente, criando um construtor parameterless ou removendo os construtores da minha classe aparentemente funcionou corretamente.
Mas existe alguma explicação para eu não poder utilizar um construtor na minha model utilizada na API?
Agradeço desde já! :)

Comment: O runtime precisará desserializar o objeto em algum momento. Se o construtor possui parâmetros, como ele saberá quais deve injetar? Ah! Se a solução deu certo, não se esqueça de aceitar a resposta.

Comment: Compreendi!
Perfeito Armindo, agradeço imensamente pelo esclarecimento! Grande abraço! :)